# Target (1 &0) Column not getting converted from str to int type

Tags: pandas, dataframe, logistic-regression, data-preprocessing

I am trying to do a Logistic Regression Project. For plotting graph i had converted 0 as "Not Looking for Change" and 1 as "Looking for Job Change" using the below code.

```
retarget = {0.0: 'Not looking for job change',
           1.0: 'Looking for job change'}
hr['target'] = hr['target'].map(retarget)
```

But after Exploratory Data Analysis I want to convert 'Not looking for Job Change' as 0 and 'Looking for Job Change' as 1.
I tried the above code again as below:

```
retarget2 = {'Not looking for job change': 0, 'Looking for job change': 1}
hr['target'] = hr.target.map(retarget2)
```

But i am getting NaN in the target values column.
Here is the snapshot of the dataset :
[image]

Please help me the solution. I am new to Python and trying to learn it.

Comment: Your code works for me. It's not the best method to use but it works. You should change your label in matplotlib (or another plotting library).

Comment: @Corralien Can u suggest any other code which can help in converting the String Values back to Numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column `target_str` instead of override `target` column and drop it when you don't need anymore.

```
retarget = {0.0: 'Not looking for job change',
           1.0: 'Looking for job change'}
hr['target_str'] = hr['target'].map(retarget)

# do what you want with target_str

hr = hr.drop(columns='target_str')
```